# How do I find spectral purity?

Tags: rf, oscillator, high-frequency, signal-to-noise, noise-spectral-density

How is spectral purity measured? or evaluated? I have this signal coming from a 10 MHz crystal oscillator. I know how to calculate the SNR, but how do I calculate the spectral purity? Is it also a ratio involving signal strength?

[image]

Comment: I believe spectral purity is the power ratio from the actual peak, to the height of the shoulder some distance away.

Comment: From what I've read its done at increments of 1 kHz away from the peak.

Comment: So, it looks like you put your marker around 5 kHz off the peak. And I think the peak is around 38 dB higher than the marker. So I guess the spectral purity is -38dBc at 5 kHz? I hope someone who actually knows will come along and answer. ;-)

Comment: The term to Google for is *Phase Noise*. And the spectrum analyser screenshot above shows mainly the shape of the spectrum analyser IF filter, not the phase noise of the oscillator. i.e. even a perfect tone would look like this.

Comment: Here's an app note from HP/Agilent, who can be considered knowledgeable. http://www.testunlimited.com/pdf/an/5952-2019.pdf

Comment: What is the IF BW?  Is that an SC cut OCXO? Or just an ATcut XO. You need to measure the spectral density of the phase noise rather than the carrier and IF , VF BW

Answer (score 1):

#### Spectral purity is the stability of a signal.

Your picture is an FFT which shows a clear peak slightly below 10 MHz. However, it's not a pure 10 MHz. A pure spectrum would be an infinitely steep spike, visible only as a vertical line.

Practical you'll never get such a pure spike. You'll always see harmonics, non-linearities, phase noise, mixing products, etc., perhaps even all of them. Your spectral purity is similar to SNR in that it's the relative amount between 'wanted' and 'unwanted' signal.

#### Spectral purity is the inverse of energy resolution.

Energy resolution is the ratio of the full-width-at-half-maximum (FWHM) of the peak divided by the centroid position of the peak. For more information take a look at [Brittanica#Spectroscopy-systems](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/1357248/radiation-measurement/80699/Spectroscopy-systems). FWHM is expressed as a ratio or a percentage. Smaller value = higher purity (so for spectral purity it would be higher value = higher purity).

Although I can't say for sure, your energy resolution seems to be lower than 2% (based on [pictures at h3dgamma](http://www.h3dgamma.com/resolution.html)).

Comment: Feel free to use the information in this answer to write a more complete answer. This is all I could think of at the moment.

Comment: I don't think that's an FFT, it's a spectrum analyzer trace. As tomnexus notes above, what's shown is the IF filter characteristic. The OP needs to reduce the Res BW further in order to see the sharp spike.

Comment: Without any specifications from the OP, I had to guess. @tomnexus his theory sounds good.